# concatenate on the third dimension for each subject

Tags: matlab, loops, concatenation, dimension

I have one file .mat for each condition (4) and each subject (24). So, I have in total 96 files .mat.
Example:

cond1_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond1_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond1_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat, etc.

cond2_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond2_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond2_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat, etc.

cond3_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond3_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond3_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat, etc.

cond4_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond4_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond4_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat, etc.

In each file, depending on the condition, I have a variable that is 66x3000single. AA1 for condition1, AA2 for condition2, AA3 for condition3, AA4 for condition4.

I would like to concatenate on the third dimension AA1,AA2,AA3,AA4 for each subject, in a loop.

So, for each subject I should obtain a 3D matrix/structure with 4 'sheets' as third dimension.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you tried something already?

Answer (score 0):

ok new try with all previous approaches deleted. Here you go. The problem was that cond_number was a string and using a string as an index created the 52, also the load (filename) was missing. However, I tried it with some dummy files and now it works, but only if your subject numbers are running from 1 to 24 and not like 1 5 7 9 19 ....  If that is the case you need to modify the code accordingly. Good luck!

```
clear all
close all
origindir = 'c:\yourdirectory';
cd (origindir)
av_files = dir(fullfile('*.mat'));
mymatrix = zeros(24,66,3000,4);


for ifile = 1:size(av_files,1)
    filename = av_files(ifile).name;
    load(filename)
    if ~isempty(str2num(filename(10:11)))
       sub_number = str2num(filename(10:11));
    else
       sub_number = str2num(filename(10));
    end
    cond_number_str = filename(5);
    cond_number = str2double(cond_number_str);
    varname = strcat('AA',cond_number_str);
    mymatrix(sub_number,:,:,cond_number)=eval(sprintf(varname));
end
for sub = 1:24
    varname2 = strcat('newmat',num2str(sub));
    eval([sprintf('%s = squeeze(mymatrix(%i,:,:,:));',varname2,sub)])
end
```

Comment: your code works fine and it creates AA1, AA2, AA3, AA4. I tried to add after `mystruct.(varname) = eval(sprintf(varname));` some lines in order to create the matrix with three dimensions: `mymatrix(:,:,1) = AA1(:,:);` `mymatrix(:,:,2) = AA2(:,:);` `mymatrix(:,:,3) = AA3(:,:);` `mymatrix(:,:,4) = AA4(:,:);` but it doesn't work. Any idea? I also tried with `mymatrix = cat(3, AA1, AA2, AA3, AA4);` but with no success.

Comment: @dede: I updated the code, so that you either have a matrix (mymatrix) or a better structured struct. The latter you could also adress in a loop to fill up mymatrix

Comment: sorry to be a pain. Maybe I was not very clear, what I would like to obtain is a matrix 66x3000x4 for each subject. At the moment, I obtain a matrix 66x3000x96, so basically one matrix for all subjects. I hope you can help...thank you!!

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It creates a variable for each subject, but a matrix of 66x3000x52 (not sure where this 52 comes from). In addition, both *mymatrix* and *newmatX* are made of zeros, so they are not replaced by the real values once in the loop..

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to proceed please? Many thanks!

Comment: normally it should do the job, also there is no part where a 52 might come up. If you have loaded one of the .mat what is `size(AA1)` and what do you get if you stop inside the second for loop and type  `sprintf('%s = squeeze(mymatrix(%i,:,:,:)) `

Comment: Thanks @horseshoe for your answer. When I type `size(AA1)` I obtain 66 3000. Instead, if I type `sprintf('%s = squeeze(mymatrix(%i,:,:,:));')` I obtain: Empty matrix: 1-by-0.

Comment: @dede I modified the answer and tested it with a dummy set. Now it should work

Comment: @dede: I created six files cond1_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond1_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond1_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat,cond2_sbj5_ToProcess_av.mat, cond2_sbj7_ToProcess_av.mat, cond2_sbj10_ToProcess_av.mat, where each cond1 has a variable AA1 with random numbers and each cond2 has an AA2 with random numbers. After running the code I get newmat1 to newmat24 each of a size of 66x3000x4 but of course only newmat5(:,:,1) newmat5(:,:,2) newmat7(:,:,1) newmat7(:,:,2) and newmat10(:,:,1)  newmat10(:,:,2) contain non-zero values as these are the only ones that were filled. Did you check the right variable?